# Symfony 2 set correct URL on inline CSS

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have a simple JavaScript file that has a function to dynamically switch a background image. The JavaScript file is included to the page via Assetic. The script sets a CSS background image property via jQuery.

How can I set the correct URL with Symfony 2 so that the CSS URL always points to the correct image? I know I could just append the JavaScript directly to the template file and set the correct URL in the template file via `{{ asset(asset_url) }}`, but I'd like to know if there is a solution to set the correct path with an external JavaScript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [JmikolaJsAssetsHelperBundle](https://github.com/jmikola/JmikolaJsAssetsHelperBundle/). It allows you to expose the AssetsHelper service from Symfony2's templating component to JavaScript. You can then generate relative and absolute asset URLs.

**Example** of using a `getUrl` asset helper to generate your image's path.

```
//javascript
<img src="' + AssetsHelper.getUrl('/images/myImage.png') + '">
```

Take a deeper look at [the documentation](https://github.com/jmikola/JmikolaJsAssetsHelperBundle/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Thanks for your second great answer for the day :)